# pass both loaded and input values ​to a function using url_for

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm trying to pass values ​​as parameters using url_for but i have some problems as i have first some data loaded by a function and then, some data inserted manually using the <input ../> constructs. How can I do?

```
<td align = "center"> <a href = "{{url_for ('insertResults', idGia = attribute [0], language = attribute [4], level = attribute [5], info = info, written = written, oral = oral, session = session)}} "type =" submit "class =" btn btn-primary "> Insert </td>
```

where info, written and oral are the data entered as input in the following ways:

```
<td align = "center"> <input type = "text" placeholder = "100" id = "info" name = "info" /> </td> 
<td align = "center"> <input type = "text" placeholder = "100" id = "written" name = "written" /> </td> 
<td align = "center"> <input type = "text" placeholder = "100" id = "oral" name = "oral" /> </td>
```

Comment: This platform lives from the fact that there are volunteers who are willing to sacrifice their time and use their knowledge to help others to solve their problems. In order to give these people feedback on the success of their measures, the users are given a wide variety of means. It would be nice if the questioner would use this to rate the answer and / or mark the question as answered. Even if you have received an answer, it is always possible to clarify any resulting ambiguities with comments. I hope that you understand my concerns and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The `url_for` function is executed on the server side. It is not possible to pass parameters from form fields to this.

Are you sure you want to use a GET request for this? It seems to me that a POST request makes more sense in your situation.

The following example shows you different methods with which you can transfer variables with a POST request and query them within your route. The data largely find their place within the request body. Only the attribute with the name "attr0" is sent within the url.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('indert_results', attr0=attr[0]) }}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="val0" value="{{ attr[1] }}" />
  <input type="text" name="val1" />
  <input type="text" name="val2" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/insert-results/<int:attr0>', methods=['POST'])
def insert_results(attr0):
    val0 = request.form['val0']
    val1 = request.form.get('val1')
    val2 = request.form.get('val1', 'default-value1')

    print(
        f'attribs: {attr0}', 
        f'values: {val0}, {val1}, {val2}', 
        sep='\n'
    )

    # ...
```

If you do insist on a GET request, I still advise you to use a form so that you can transfer the entries from the form fields as query parameters.
All data is transmitted in different sections of the url. The query parameters are added to the url in the form "?param0=value0&param1=value1".

```
<form action="{{ url_for('insert_results', attr0=attr[0], attr1=attr[1]) }}" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="param0" />
  <input type="text" name="param1" />
  <input type="text" name="param2" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/insert-results/<int:attr0>-<str:attr1>', methods=['GET'])
def insert_results(attr0, attr1):
    param0 = request.args['param0']
    param0 = request.args.get('param1')
    param1 = request.args.get('param2', 'default-value2')

    print(
        f'attribs: {attr0}, {attr1}', 
        f'params: {param0}, {param1}, {param2}'
        sep='\n'
    )
    
    # ...
```

Regardless of whether you use the form or ask for the arguments within the url, you use a kind of dictionary which allows you to use `.get(key [, default] [, type = <func_ptr>])` to ensure that a `KeyError` is bypassed, a default value is passed and possibly the type of the value is converted.

Choose the transmission method wisely and consider the visibility of the data for third parties, taking into account that the transmission may later take place in encrypted form. You should also consider the amount of data you want to send. The more data you want to transfer, the sooner you will switch to a POST request.

Especially with several data records that are transmitted individually, you can later think of a transmission using ajax. However, this is a more complex solution and the explanation would lead too far at this point.